# Vue router use keep-alive to cache certain components?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have started working with vue recently, and I have managed to create some simple pages, but I have noticed that the component once loaded are not cached, therefore for example on link below (which is what I am working on) youtube videos take time to load, and if I click on any other link and come back to videos they are loaded again.

Is it possible to use  to cache components? preferably all of them instead of 1 by 1.

Here's my vue:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Create from '../components/homepage/create.vue';
import How from '../components/homepage/how.vue';
import About from '../components/homepage/about.vue';
import Youtube from '../components/homepage/youtube.vue';
import Navigation from '../components/homeNavigation.vue';
import Login from '../components/auth/login.vue';
import Register from '../components/auth/register.vue';


const routes = [
    { path: '/create', component: Create },
    { path: '/how', component: How },
    { path: '/about', component: About},
    { name: 'youtube', path: '/youtube', component: Youtube},
    { path: '/login', component: Login},
    { path: '/register', component: Register},
];

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.component('navigation', Navigation);

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    updated: function () {
        Pace.restart()
    },
    mounted: function() {
        Pace.restart()
    }
});
```

View:

```
<div id="app">
        <navigation></navigation>
            <transition appear name="slide-fade" mode="in-out">
                <keep-alive include='youtube'>
                    <router-view></router-view>
                </keep-alive>
            </transition>
</div>
```

My app:

http://b2750916.ngrok.io/#/youtube

Comment: I'm not sure that would fix it, but I would give a try to the [v-once](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-once) directive

Comment: Have you maybe tried with something else than videos (that are probably "iframed"). Because keep-alive should cache component data. But by data I do not mean YT video's... Possible to get more details ? Like what does youtube component do?

Comment: Does your Youtube component have a name property equal to 'youtube'?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116616/keep-alive-on-a-single-route-instaead-of-all-routes-in-router-view/43131202#43131202

Answer (score 9):

Check this answer here:
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/keep-alive-specific-component/2372/2

Since v2.1 You can use "include" and "exclude" attributes as regex for controlling which component will be cached. These attributes can also be v-bind'ed:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive

Another way is by using the `deactivated` hook on the components you don't want to keep cached. In the hook, you call `this.$destroy();` which removes the component under cache when it's not used.

Also, maybe this could help you?
https://github.com/LinusBorg/portal-vue

Not sure if portal-vue would work, but my thinking is place the video outside so that it render independently (in a "portal" placed in the root component) and make it appear where you want using a "portal-target".

Comment: For activated/deactivated hooks!