# How to make certain component "keep-alive" with router-view in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

I've created a small app that consists of two main components and I am using vue router to route between components.

First component is called MoviesList and the second one is called Movie.
I've registered them in routes js file.

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: MoviesList
  },

  {
    path: '/:movieId',
    name: 'Movie',
    component: Movie
  }
  
]
```

And my App.vue template looks like this

```
<template>
   <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

How can I make MovieList component cached or so to say like it is wrapped with `<keep-alive>` tags?
Desired outcome would be to make MovieList component cached and Movie component not.

I want to do that because MovieList component has a method that runs on mounted() hook and whenever I switch routes and come back that method runs again because component is re-rendered.

Answer (score 20):

try this `include="MoviesList"`,or `exclude="Movie"` also work

```
<router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
  <keep-alive include="MoviesList">
    <component :is="Component" />
  </keep-alive>
</router-view>
```

Comment: Make sure your component has a name set (`export default { name: '...'}`) - the default name based on the component filename won't work. Also, more info on the router-view new slot api is here: https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#router-view-s-v-slot

Comment: Also - if you use script setup you need to add another `<script>` tag above `<script setup>` and `export default { name: 'MoviesList' }`, because it doesn't work otherwise. `script setup` doesn't set component names explicitly. See https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/discussions/273?sort=top

Answer (score 6):

Try to use `keep-alive` inside `router-view` and render it conditionally based on the current component :

```
<router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
 <template v-if="Component.name==='movie-list'">
    <keep-alive>
      <component :is="Component" />
    </keep-alive>
 </template>
<template v-else>
     <component :is="Component" />
</template>

</router-view>
```

Answer (score 2):

For Vue.js 2.0, this example helped me a lot!

https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/L613xva0/4/

Basically, the **key** is to make sure you use the **component name** in the *include*:

```html
<keep-alive include="componentname">
  <router-view></router-view>
</keep-alive>
```

```js
const MyComponent = {
  name: 'componentname',
  template: '<div>My awesome component!</div>'
}

const routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MyComponent
  }
]
```

Comment: New link https://jsfiddle.net/kgcupret/7/ because in old VueRouter is undefined (URL for its is not working now)